# Extracting a number from "list of rules" to a vector?

Tags: r

I have a list containing rules for certain number of trials, such as rules[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKn5p.jpg)] outputs  set of 123 rules, rules[[2]] outputs set of 32 rules.Now, I have to get those numbers (123,32 ->number of rules)in a vector? It's not a string it's a List with items as Rules derived using apriori algorithm.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please be sure to read about providing a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have a look at making a [reproducible R example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Images are generally not the way to share your example data.

Comment: You may be looking for `lengths(thelist)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(thelist, '\\d+'))
#[1] 450 396
```

#### data

```
thelist <- list("set of 450 rules", "set of 396 rules")
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time. The above code u have posted would definitely help me in the future